# Distinguish overloaded methods in Kotlin reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

I have two methods:

```
class Example {
    fun method(name: String): String {}

    fun method(name: String, length: Int): String {}
}
```

And at some point in my code I need to use the second version of `method` via reflection, like so:

```
val func = Example::method
```

This can't compile because the compiler can't tell the difference between the two definitions of this overloaded method. I can't find a way to specify the parameteres for the function. The documentation says:

> Alternatively, you can provide the necessary context by storing the method reference in a variable with an explicitly specified type:
>
> `val predicate: (String) -> Boolean = ::isOdd   // refers to isOdd(x: String)`

But in my case, the function assigned to `func` can be arbitrary, it does not necessarily has two parameters of types `String` and `Int`, and in other cases the function assigned to this property only has the single `String` parameter. But in this case, I need the version with two parameters.

So, is there any way to specify which function I'm using, and if not, is there any workaround?

Comment: but how are you going to use `val func`? you have to call it  either by `func("name")` or `func("name", 1)`  at compile time. which means you need to know the function definition beforehand

Comment: @sidgate  That's a rational concern, and perhaps my way of addressing this is not the best. I am not calling it, however, I am using it for code generation with KotlinPoet. This way instead of storing function name, package and parameters separately to use those later (I need to generate a function call) I can store just one object. Later when I generate said call, I check function parameters (there are several similar functions that all have a `length: Int` parameter, for example) and handle those accordingly.

Comment: may be you can try reflection methods like `memberFunctions` or java style `getMethod`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with reflection is that a function reference always refers to one particular function. So in your case you would need 2 function references to match both versions of `method`:

```
val e = Example()
val func1: (String) -> String      = e::method 
val func2: (String, Int) -> String = e::method
```

And this would most certainly not meet the need why you overloaded the function since you either have to use `func1` or `func2` respectively

Another approach would be to use a function with default parameter(s) instead of overloading.
In addition I declared the original functions private and use a public wrapper instead to have both functions still separated:

(for sure you can also define just one `method` function with optional parameter as well and differentiate within this function):

```
class Example
{
    private fun method(name: String): String {
       return "Method1: $name"
    }

    private fun method(name: String, length: Int): String {
       return "Method2: $name ($length)"
    }

    fun method(name: String, length: Int? = null) : String {
        if (length == null)
           return method(name)
        else
           return method(name, length)
    }
} 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val e = Example()
    
    // local function because lambda expression cannot have default parameters
    fun func (name: String, length: Int? = null): String {
        return e.method(name, length)
    }
    
    println(func("John"))
    println(func("Doe", 42))
}
```